# Collecting π infinite series: Mystery Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, pi, approximate-integration

---

I am new to this forum, but I am hoping I can ask for your help. I have recently been interested in finding and recording as many infinite series apporximating π as I can find. There is one in particular I have noted on an old copybook, but I have not seen it anywhere else. I will write it here hoping that someone might recognize it and tell me if it is in fact an approximating series of π and who came up with it.

$\pi=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{4}{n\left(1+\left(\frac{i-\frac{1}{2}}{n}\right)^2\right)}$

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is N in the series , the series is summing over I , what is N ?

Comment: You mean "$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{4}{1+((i-1/2)/n)^2}$".

Answer (score 4):

You mean $$  \pi = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{4}{1+\left( \frac{i-1/2}{n} \right)^2}  \text{,}  $$
which is a [midpoint Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Midpoint_rule) for the integral 
$$  \int_0^1 \; \frac{4}{1+x^2} \,\mathrm{d}x = \pi  \text{.}  $$
This evaluation follows a straightforward trigonometric substitution, $x = \tan \theta$:  \begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \; \frac{4}{1+x^2} \,\mathrm{d}x 
    &= \int_0^{\pi/4} \; \frac{4 \sec^2 \theta} {1+\tan^2 \theta} \,\mathrm{d}\theta  \\
    &= \int_0^{\pi/4} \; 4 \,\mathrm{d}\theta  \\
    &= 4\left( \frac{\pi}{4} - 0 \right)  \\
    &= \pi  \text{.}
\end{align*}